# iterate over strings and move pattern to start of each list element

Tags: python, regex, loops, replace, substring

I have a list of `names` that have the title `Dr.` in the wrong place.

Therefore i would like to

- loop over the list elements to replace either `Dr.,` or `Dr.` with
- while also adding/moving `Dr.`  to the start of the corresponding strings.

my result is rather disappointing. Is `re.sub()` even the right approach?

```
names = ['Johnson, Dr., PWE', 'Peterson, FDR', 'Gaber, Dr. GTZ']
for idx, item in enumerate(names):
    names[idx] = re.sub(r' Dr.(,)? ', ' Dr. ', item)
print(names)
['Johnson, Dr. PWE', 'Peterson, FDR', 'Gaber, Dr. GTZ']
```

---

```
desired_names = ['Dr. Johnson, PWE', 'Peterson, FDR', 'Dr. Gaber, GTZ']
```

Comment: Try `re.sub(r'^(.*?)\s*\b(Dr\.),?', r'\2 \1', text)` - https://regex101.com/r/05IUlk/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 2 capture groups, and use those reverted in the replacement to get the right order.

```
([^,\n]+,\s*)(Dr\.),?\s*
```

- `([^,\n]+,\s*)` Capture any char except `,` or a newline in *group 1*, then match a comma and optional whitespace char
- `(Dr\.)` Capture `Dr.` in *group 2*
- `,?\s*` Match an optional comma and whitespace chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VFfGLf/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/8rx8Gt)

Example

```
import re
names = ['Johnson, Dr., PWE', 'Peterson, FDR', 'Gaber, Dr. GTZ']
for idx, item in enumerate(names):
    names[idx] = re.sub(r'([^,\n]+,\s*)(Dr\.),?\s*', r'\2 \1', item)
print(names)
```

Output

```
['Dr. Johnson, PWE', 'Peterson, FDR', 'Dr. Gaber, GTZ']
```